# Office Addin software update options

Tags: .net, vsto, ms-office, installation

Our team has created VSTO addin in VS 2010. We are now exploring options for updating the add-in once installed on the end user system.

We are currently distributing the application using an installer. Within the office app the user gets some visual clue regarding the availability of a new version of add-in. I am exploring ways on how to actually update the add-in install directory.
One option is to alert user from the application (Word, Excel) regarding the availability of new add-in including its download location. The user then downloads a new setup file manually and updates.

What are the other mechanism that we can explorer.

Answer (score 0):

My preference is to use Click Once for deployment, but this often has issues around updates.

I have created a nice wrapper for doing ClickOnce updates via code in VSTO projects, have  a look at http://vstocontrib.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/50a83624e34d#src%2fVSTOContrib.Core%2fVstoClickOnceUpdater.cs

It deals with all the odd security stuff, and deals with the different versions of VSTOInstaller.exe.